# ¿Cómo sumo solo el lado de un Binary Search Tree en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Recibo una función que tiene por parámetros dos argumentos, side y total=0, debo agregar el método get(), que al pasarle un string me devuelva la suma de los nodos de ese lado. Por ejemplo myTree('left'), debe devolver la suma de los nodos de ese lado.
Si recibes el parámetro "right", debes retornar la suma de todos los valores que estén a la derecha.

EJEMPLOS:

```
Dado el siguiente árbol:
                13
             /      \
           7         24
         /          /   \
        6         16     27
      /                    \
     3                     45
      \
       4
```

BinarySearchTree.get("left") Devuelve => 16.

Mi código hasta ahora, lo he trabajado así:

```
function BinarySearchTree(valor){
  this.value = valor;
  this.left = null;
  this.right = null;
}
BinarySearchTree.prototype.insert = function(value) {
  if(value < this.value){
    if(this.left === null){
      var newTree = new BinarySearchTree(value);
      this.left = newTree;
    } else {
      this.left.insert(value);
    }
  } else {
    if(this.right === null){
      var newTree = new BinarySearchTree(value);
      this.right = newTree;
    } else {
      this.right.insert(value);
    }
  }
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.size = function() {
  if(this.value === null){
    return 0;
  }
  if(this.left === null && this.right === null){
    return 1;
  }
  if(this.left === null){
    return 1 + this.right.size();
  }
  if(this.right === null){
    return 1 + this.left.size();
  }
  return 1 + this.left.size() + this.right.size();
}
BinarySearchTree.prototype.get = function(side,total=0){
  
  if(side === 'left'){
    total = total + this.left.get();
    console.log(total)
  }
  if(side === 'right'){
    total += this.right.get();
  }
  return total + this.value;
  }

let miArbol1 = new BinarySearchTree(15);
miArbol1.insert(7);
miArbol1.insert(24);
miArbol1.insert(27);
miArbol1.insert(16);
miArbol1.insert(6);
miArbol1.insert(3);
miArbol1.insert(4);
miArbol1.insert(45);

//console.log(miArbol1)
console.log(miArbol1.get('left'));// 22 ¿?
```

No se donde estoy cometiendo el error, ya que me suma el root con el primer nodo.

Answer (score 1):

en la obtención de la suma de los nodos, ya sea de izquierda 'left' o de derecha 'right', debemos implementar condicionales anidados, ya que esto nos permitirá seguir  buscando los valores en la respectiva rama:

El código queda así:

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.get = function (side, total = 0) {
  if(side === 'left'){
    if(this.left){
      total += this.left.get('left');
    }
    }else{
     if(side === 'right'){
       if(this.right){
         total += this.right.get('right');
       }
     }
    }
    if(side === 'left'){
      if(this.left){
        return total + this.left.value;
      }else{
        return total;
      }
    }else{
      if(this.right){
        return total + this.right.value;
      }else{
        return total;
      }
    }
}
```

Ahora ya nos suma correctamente cada rama.